# New command with three optional arguments for chemfig

Tags: tikz-pgf, chemfig, xparse

This works fine.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations, decorations.markings, positioning}
\begin{document}
\chemfig{
    H-[,,,,draw=none,
        postaction={decorate},
        decoration={
        markings,
        mark = at position 0.22 with {\fill[red] circle[radius=1pt];},
        mark = at position 0.5 with {\fill[red] circle[radius=1pt];},
        mark = at position 1-0.22 with {\fill[red] circle[radius=1pt];}
        }
    ]O
}
\end{document}
```

This doesn’t work.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations, decorations.markings, positioning}
\usepackage{xparse}

\NewDocumentCommand \cfhbond { O{red} O{1} O{0.22} } {%
    draw=none,
    postaction={decorate},
    decoration={
        markings,
        mark = at position #3 with {\fill[#1] circle[radius=#2pt];},
        mark = at position 0.5 with {\fill[#1] circle[radius=#2pt];},
        mark = at position 1-#3 with {\fill[#1] circle[radius=#2pt];}
    }%
}

\begin{document}
\chemfig{H-[,,,,\cfhbond]O}
\chemfig{H-[,,,,\cfhbond{blue}{1.5}{0.25}]O}
\end{document}
```

It is possible to create such a command?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is what styles and pgf keys are for: rather than defining a command with many options for which you need to recall the order, you can use a style with optional pgf keys. You can set some initial values which you may think of as default values, and change the keys on the fly. This works right out of the box, and no expansion issues arise here.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations, decorations.markings, positioning}
\tikzset{cfhbond/.style={% 
    /utils/exec=\tikzset{cfh/.cd,#1},
    draw=none,
    postaction={decorate},
    decoration={
        markings,
        mark = at position \pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/cfh/position} with {\fill[\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/cfh/color}] circle[radius=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/cfh/radius}*1pt];},
        mark = at position 0.5 with {\fill[\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/cfh/color}] circle[radius=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/cfh/radius}*1pt];},
        mark = at position 1-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/cfh/position} with {\fill[\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/cfh/color}] circle[radius=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/cfh/radius}*1pt];}
    }%
},cfh/.cd,color/.initial=red,radius/.initial=1,position/.initial=0.22} % { O{red} O{1} O{0.22} } {%

\begin{document}
\chemfig{H-[,,,,cfhbond]O}
\chemfig{H-[,,,,cfhbond={color=blue,radius=1.5,position=0.25}]O}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Another advantage of this approach is that this is upgradable without pain. You want to make another parameter flexible? No problem, make it a pgf key. The old usage will still work.

Comment: Out of the libraries, only `\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}` is needed here.

Comment: Thank you, you’re amazing!